# How to import a type (from another file) inside a `d.ts` file without turning it into a module?

Tags: typescript, import, namespaces, typescript-typings

Just ran into a weird situation regarding `d.ts` files and namespaces.

I have some `d.ts` files where I declare and merge a `namespace` named `PROJECT`.

See below how it's declared and automatically merged (across multile files):

**file1.d.ts** ----- **file2.d.ts** ----- **file3.d.ts**

```
declare namespace PROJECT {

  interface SOME_INTERFACE {
    ...
  }

  type SOME_TYPE = SOME_UNION_TYPE

  // ETC
}
```

That `PROJECT` namespace is automatically accessible from every file of my project. Example:

**SomeComponent.tsx**

```
const someVariable: PROJECT.SOME_INTERFACE = { 
  // ... 
};
```

This is all expected behavior.

My problem started when I decided to declare another namespace.

**ADMIN_BLOGPOST.d.ts**

```
import type { ACTION_THUNK_GENERIC } from "@hooks/useReducerThunk";

declare namespace ADMIN_BLOGPOST {
  // HERE I DECLARE MULTIPLE TYPES
  // AND ONE OF THE TYPES USES THE `ACTION_THUNK_GENERIC` TYPE, WHICH IS BEING IMPORTED HERE

  type ACTION_THUNK = ACTION_THUNK_GENERIC<ACTION,GET_STATE>
}
```

And just because of that top-level `import type` of the `ACTION_THUNK_GENERIC`, now my namespace is not automatically available anymore.

VSCode started to consider `ADMIN_BLOGPOST.d.ts` as a module and started making me have to `import` that namespace before using it, like:

**SomeComponent.tsx**

```
import type { ADMIN_BLOGPOST } from "@src/types/ADMIN_BLOGPOST";

const someVariable: ADMIN_BLOGPOST.ACTION_THUNK
```

Note that if I remove that top-level import (the one that imports `ACTION_THUNK_GENERIC`) from the `ADMIN_BLOGPOST.d.ts` file, then my `ADMIN_BLOGPOST` namespace becomes available without the need to `import` it first.

But I really need that import. Because I need the `ACTION_THUNK_GENERIC` type so I can build the non-generic `ACTION_THUNK` type.

Is there a different way to do this so my `ADMIN_BLOGPOST` namespace is available without having to import it before using? I.e: How to `import` inside a `d.ts` file without turning it into a module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `declare global` to work in a global namespace irrespective of module imports. For example:

```
import type { ACTION_THUNK_GENERIC } from "@hooks/useReducerThunk";
declare global {
  declare namespace ADMIN_BLOGPOST {
    type ACTION_THUNK = ACTION_THUNK_GENERIC<ACTION,GET_STATE>
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can use a dynamic import:

```
declare namespace ADMIN_BLOGPOST {
  type ACTION_THUNK = import("@hooks/useReducerThunk").ACTION_THUNK_GENERIC<ACTION,GET_STATE>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not know that. But just found out another solution that you can add to the answer to make it more complete. The "dynamic" import syntax as in: `type ACTION_THUNK = import("@hooks/useReducerThunk").ACTION_THUNK_GENERIC<ACTION,GET_STATE>`. This is an alternative from using `declare global`.

Comment: Thanks. Added 

Comment: Is `ASYNC_THUNK_GENERIC` supposed to be `ACTION_THUNK_GENERIC`?

Comment: @EdStaub yes! I've fixed id. Thanks.